# SFTP Support in Azure Data Factory doesn't working?

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-data-factory

When I try to use the SFTP Connection in Azure Data Factory given at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-sftp-connector the type Value as **"sftp"** shows with an Error like **Value is not accepted** !

Comment: I get the same behaviour. I will try to check this internally.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to insert your configuration/error message as text. Don't use pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the confusion. We will fix this UX issue. But this won't block you to really deploy the SFTP pipeline. Please go ahead.
Besides, I strongly recommend you to try CopyWizard(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-copy-wizard) to create pipeline, which will have better user experience.

Regards,
Gary

Comment: After Ignoring the Ux Issue,when i tried to create a linked service as SFTP the error came while deployment as                                         
**The type properties of resource 'Sftp' do not conform to the schema of the registered type Sftp, Details: 2 validation issue(s): Value must be one of the following types: integer Value must be one of the following types: boolean 0 sanity issue(s): .**

Comment: please take care the data type of the value you input: e.g. when specify port, please input 22 (int) instead of "22" (string) and when specify skipHostKeyValidation, input true rather than "true"

Comment: @Jayendran Rosh, we have fixed the UX issue, so if the format is correct, you won't see the annoying green line now.